# Differential equations: How do I solve: $x' = x^2 - 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help, I need to find the explicit solution, I get to $(x-1)/(x+1) = e^{2t} + k^2$ but I don´t know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: let $y:=\frac{x-1}{x+1}.$ Then, $x=\frac{1+y}{1-y}.$

Comment: BTW, what you got is wrong. (Specifically, the exponentiation part. The integration is fine.)

Comment: I like to emphasize the constant solutions at $x=1$   and $x=-1.$  Thus there are three nonconstant solutions, one with $x > 1,$   one with $-1 < x < 1,$  then one with $x < -1$  These may be found with partial fractions

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical separable differential equation, which can be solved with the following integral transformation. Let $x=x(t)$, then

$$\begin{align*}
x' &= x^2-1 \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= x^2-1 \\
dx &= (x^2-1)dt \\
\frac{dx}{x^2-1} &= dt \\
\int \frac{1}{x^2-1}dx &= \int 1 dt \\
\int \frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}dx &= t + c_1
\end{align*}$$

With the partial fraction decomposition $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{1/2}{x-1}-\frac{1/2}{x+1}$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{x-1}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{x+1}dx &= t + c_1 \\
\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+1) \right) &= t+c_1 \\
\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right) &= 2t+c_2 \\
\frac{x-1}{x+1} &= c_3 e^{2t} \\
\frac{x+1-1-1}{x+1} &= c_3 e^{2t} \\
1-\frac{2}{x+1} &= c_3 e^{2t} \\
1-c_3 e^{2t} &= \frac{2}{x+1} \\
x+1 &= \frac{2}{1-c_3e^{2t}} \\
x &= \frac{2}{1-c_3e^{2t}} - 1
\end{align*}$$

So the solution is
$$\boxed{x = x(t) = \frac{2}{1-ce^{2t}}-1, \quad c\in\mathbb{R}}$$

---

You can check that this really works, as

$$x' = \frac{4ce^{2t}}{(1-ce^{2t})^2} = x^2-1$$

Comment: +1 but I think $\ln(x-1)-\ln(x+1)$ and
$\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$ should be replaced by $\ln|x-1|-\ln|x+1|$ and $
\ln\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|.$